# What is wrong about that person?

Tags: knowledge

> I once was in a relationship with Ms. Litson. Things were OK, I guess.      But not before too long, I could see that I could not keep up with her. Things were slipping. I couldn't bear this, it brought me to my
>   knees. Sometimes I thought that nothing was wrong, she was laughing,
>   singing, trying to keep thing straight....and then I woke up. I'm
>   blabbing too much; I went to great lengths, but in the end I confess I
>   was blind. I'm gonna miss Mary.

When I heard the story above, I obviously understood something wrongly. What?

Massive Hint:

> It's about a song

Comment: `enigmatic-puzzle` tag maybe?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mary Litson is

> a misunderstanding of the words **my religion** from the song "Loosing my religion" from REM
>  There are many parallels of the songtext from Loosing my religion to the story of "Mary Litson"

Comment: Oh yeah! True story, happened to me!